# multiplicación de datos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

hola amigos estoy tratando de multiplicar datos según un numero ingresado estos datos son llamado por SQL el problema es que tengo que multiplicar de la siguiente manera: Nbatida(numero por el que se multiplica) multiplica cantidad y cantidad a importe. dependiendo de el Nbatida se debe reflejar cuanta será la cantidad de material que se usara y cuanto es el costo de esa, les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

```
function setNbatida(event, obj, idx){
    event.preventDefault();
    detalles[idx].Nbatida = parseInt(obj.value);
    recalcular(idx);
  }  
  function recalcular(idx){
    console.log(detalles[idx].Nbatida);
    console.log((detalles[idx].Nbatida * detalles[idx].cantidad * detalles[idx].precio));
    console.log((detalles[idx].Nbatida * detalles[idx].cantidad));
    var importe =detalles[idx].importe = detalles[idx].Nbatida * detalles[idx].cantidad * detalles[idx].precio;
    var cantidad = detalles[idx].cantidad =detalles[idx].Nbatida * detalles[idx].cantidad;
    importe = detalles[idx].importe = detalles[idx].importe;
    cantidad = detalles[idx].cantidad = detalles[idx].cantidad;   
    importeFinal = detalles[idx].moneda+" "+importe;
    cantidadFinal = detalles[idx].cantidad;
    $('#importe'+idx).html(importeFinal);
    $('#cantidad'+idx).html(cantidadFinal);
    calcularTotales();
  }
  function calcularTotales(){  
   var subtotal = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var subtotalFinal = 0;
    var totalFinal = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<detalles.length; i++){
      if(detalles[i].estado == 1){
      subtotal = subtotal + (detalles[i].Nbatida * detalles[i].cantidad * detalles[i].precio) - (detalles[i].Nbatida*detalles[i].cantidad*detalles[i].precio);
            subtotalFinal = detalles[i].moneda+" "+subtotal;
            var su = subtotal;
            var or=parseFloat(su);
            var total = Math.round(or+subtotal);
            totalFinal = detalles[i].moneda+" "+total;        
    }
  }
  $('#subtotal').html(subtotalFinal);
  $('#subtotal_Batida').html(subtotalFinal);
  $('#total').html(totalFinal);
  $('#total_Batida').html(totalFinal);
  }
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es el problema y dónde?

Comment: en var importe =detalles[idx].importe = detalles[idx].Nbatida * detalles[idx].cantidad * detalles[idx].precio;  var cantidad = detalles[idx].cantidad =detalles[idx].Nbatida * detalles[idx].cantidad;

Comment: cuando le doy click se sigue multiplicando ya no por el dato que traia de la abse si no por el nuevo de cantidad(el dato que se multiplico)

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica el problema en la pregunta. Creo que si haces una depuración de los valores y de las operaciones podrás encontrar el problema. Usa `console.log` para verificar cada etapa del código. Me parece que es un simple problema de depuración. Si aún así no lo resuelves puedes indicar en la pregunta lo que hayas depurado, con cuáles resultados y te ayudaremos. Es importante que aprendas a depurar tu propio código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener muy claro lo que deseas hacer y cómo hacerlo:

1. Modifica solo contenedores HTML al realizar los cálculos
2. Si acaso, solo deberías actualizar importe en el arreglo de detalles
3. Al calcular totales, dentro del ciclo solo haz una sumatoria de importes, no es necesario modificar otras variables
4. `subtotal = subtotal + otroValor` es lo mismo que `subtotal += otroValor`, pero lo segundo es más sencillo

```
function setNbatida(event, obj, idx){
    event.preventDefault();
    detalles[idx].Nbatida = parseInt(obj.value);
    recalcular(idx);
}  
function recalcular(idx){
    console.log(detalles[idx].Nbatida);
    console.log((detalles[idx].Nbatida * detalles[idx].cantidad * detalles[idx].precio));
    console.log((detalles[idx].Nbatida * detalles[idx].cantidad));
    // Define variables locales, solo las necesarias para simplificar
    let cantidad = detalles[idx].cantidad * detalles[idx].Nbatida;
    let importe = cantidad * detalles[idx].precio;

    // Modifica los contenedores HTML
    $('#importe'+idx).html(detalles[idx].moneda + ' ' + importe);
    $('#cantidad'+idx).html(cantidad);

    // ¿Necesitas realmente actualizar algo en detalles?
    // Quizá solo el importe
    detalles[idx].importe = importe;

    calcularTotales();
}
function calcularTotales(){  
    let subtotal = 0;
    let total = 0;
    let subtotalFinal = 0;
    let totalFinal = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<detalles.length; i++){
        if(detalles[i].estado == 1){
            // Estás sumando y restando lo mismo, no tiene sentido
            // subtotal += (detalles[i].Nbatida * detalles[i].cantidad * detalles[i].precio) - (detalles[i].Nbatida * detalles[i].cantidad * detalles[i].precio);

            // Ya deberías tener un importe en detalles[i]... ¿o no?
            subtotal += detalles[i].importe;

            // Todavía no deberías modificar, solo hasta salir del ciclo
            /*
            subtotalFinal = detalles[i].moneda+" "+subtotal;
            var su = subtotal;
            var or=parseFloat(su);
            var total = Math.round(or+subtotal);
            totalFinal = detalles[i].moneda+" "+total;
            */
        }
    }
    $('#subtotal').html(detalles[i].moneda + ' ' + subtotal);
    $('#subtotal_Batida').html(detalles[i].moneda + ' ' + subtotal);
    totalFinal = Math.round(subtotal);
    $('#total').html(detalles[i].moneda + ' ' + totalFinal);
    $('#total_Batida').html(detalles[i].moneda + ' ' + totalFinal);
}
```

Comment: ya veo. tenia muchas cosas que hacian que no funcionara bien

Comment: muchas gracias amigo

Comment: en serio te agradezco en todo lo que  me has ayudado

Comment: amigo si quiero actualizar cantidad de la misma forma

Comment: debo modificar la parte de los contenedores y agregar detalles[idx].cantidad = importe; ?

Comment: @wilbertpalacios, no modifiques el arreglo de `detalles` a menos que sea necesario y, en este caso, creo que solo el importe es el que se va a cambiar después de actualizar los contenedores: `detalles[idx].importe = importe;`

Comment: Por cierto, después de eso, se me había pasado ejecutar `calcularTotales();` nuevamente.

Comment: y si deseo cambiar tambien la cantidad? que mande la cantidad ya multiplicada a guardar

Comment: Si haces eso, entonces vas a meterte en problemas nuevamente con el cálculo; en todo caso, crea una nueva propiedad, por ejemplo: `detalles[idx].cantidadReal = cantidad;` y entonces vas a usar `cantidad` para calcular y `cantidadReal` para guardar.

Comment: ok tratare de esa manera